# Get elements from list using index from a list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

> **Question:**

I have a list of arrays such as:

```
a = [array([0, 4]), array([1, 3, 2])]
```

From another variable X, I want to take two subsets which are chosen by the index in each array in a.

```
X = [0.1, 0.7, 0.9, 0.2, 0.3]
```

What I want to have is now:

```
result_1 = [0.1, 0.3]
result_2 = [0.7, 0.2, 0.9]
```

My solution would be to use a for loop such as:

```
def getresult(X, indices):
     result = []
     for i in indices:
          result.append(X[i])
     return result
```

This works fine:

```
getresult(X, a[0])
[0.1, 0.3]
```

My previous experience with programming suggest, that there is a much more beautiful and simple way to do so and that this is the place to ask. 
Preferably someone would know a solution that does not need looping.

> **Background/application:**

Background: Crossvalidation for parameter optimization.

I have a `list` containing datapoints such as

```
X = [0.1, 0.7, 0.9, 0.2, 0.3]
```

Now I want to repeatedly take z samples out of that list (which actually is much bigger than this example). Therefore I create a new variable:

```
indices = np.arange(0,len(X),1)

HERE: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Which then i shuffle and create nfold samples:

```
np.random.shuffle(indices)        
nfold_indices = np.array_split(indices,nfolds)

HERE with nfolds = 2: nfold_indices = [array([0, 4]), array([1, 3, 2])]
```

Comment: Are you sure that your solution is working with `a[1]`?

Comment: Just tested it again, yes it does work.

Comment: Indeed, sorry, I misread your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension, with a default for safety, in case an index from `a` is not in `X`:

```
a = [array('i', [0, 4]), array('i', [1, 3, 2])]
X = [0.1, 0.7, 0.9, 0.2, 0.3] 

result = [[(X[i:]+[0])[0] for i in o] for o in a]
#                  ^ default
# [[0.1, 0.3], [0.7, 0.2, 0.9]]
```

So in the event you have an arbitrary array containing an out of range index:

```
a = [array('i', [0, 4]), array('i', [1, 3, 20])]
#                                           ^ out of range
result = [[(X[i:]+[0])[0] for i in o] for o in a]
# [[0.1, 0.3], [0.7, 0.2, 0]]
#                         ^
```

Your code does not break

Comment: Something I never liked... ask a list for the element 20, and it raises an IndexError, ask the list to give you elements 20 and forward and will return quietly an empty list...

Comment: Well, that functionality comes handy in cases like this.

Comment: I find: result = [[ X[i] if i < len(X) else 0 for i in o] for o in a]  more readable in that case... Does not rely on people knowing that particular detail and also works if X is an array.

Comment: @Jblasco That won't work for `i = -1`. It returns `0` instead of the last element in the list.

Comment: Indeed, you are right... That's the problem one tries to go too compact and readable. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

`return [X[i] for i in indices]` would work.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt, which basically follows your way of doing things in a more compact way would be:

```
result1, result2 = [ [X[ii] for ii in array] for array in a]
```

If you can be bothered to convert X to a numpy array, you can do:

```
X = np.array([ 0.1,  0.7,  0.9,  0.2,  0.3])
result1, result2 = X[a[0]], X[a[1]]
```

But this has the problem that it does not generalise well for more than a few arrays within a. Even if some people will hate me for using a lambda, another compact way of doing it that generalises better is:

```
results = map(lambda x: X[x], a)
```

Comment: why would some hate anyone for using lambda ?

Comment: jejeje, there is a forever-ongoing religious war between people that love and people that hate lambdas. I'm quite indiferent, but see for example: http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1298

Guido  van Rossum himself had some things to say about lambdas.